# Signals-slots TabWidget

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, pyside

I have created a small app, in which I use the a QTabWidget and user request on it adds and deletes tabs(when I add one it actually creates the widget to be added as well), then the current tab should be connected to the other Gui parts such a buttons QlineEdit and a progress bar, my question is when I remove the page and delete the widget inside the page, do the connections to signals and slots get removed automatically or should I just disconnect them manually?

Thanks in advance to anyone who will answer. A pyside newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question and I hope it will be helpull to someone else. Yes when you delete the child widget inside the tabwidget, the connection gets deleted automatically. For more info here is a reference from "GUI Programming with Python: QT Edition" https://www.commandprompt.com/community/pyqt/x1631.htm